# Subset data in R to look at specefic country

Tags: r

I am currently using the EVS data. It is a panel data from 1981-2021. This has 223099 obvs and 635 variables. One of the variables of interest is the country. I am trying to subset the data frame to only look at one country but at the same time look at the other variables. I am not sure what to do.
I input the code:

```r
data <-subset(data,COW_NUM == "339")
```

Where `COW_NUM` is the country number. 339 is the country of interest

I keep getting an error message. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Is `COW_NUM` character or numeric? If numeric, omit the quote marks

Comment: Please read the info at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and in particiular provide complete code and inputs so anyone can clearly understand what the setup is and reproduce it in their session.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide a link to the data?

`my_data`: this is your data
`my_data$COW_NUM`: this is the column that you want to use to filter

In R if you do `my_data$COW_NUM == "339"` ("339" is is string ?), R will return a vector of TRUE/FALSE value (223099 TRUE/FALSE if I understand correctly). R will check if each value of `my_data$COW_NUM` == `339` if yes it return TRUE if not FALSE.

Then you can use this new vector inside `[` to subset `my_data`:

`my_data[my_data$COW_NUM == "339",]` will keep every rows of `my_data` where `my_data$COW_NUM == "339"` give a TRUE and discard the one with FALSE.

Last step should be:

`my_data_339 <- my_data[my_data$COW_NUM == "339",]`

Hope it help but it is hard to do it without the data!